# When does Clojure check if recur appears in tail position?

Tags: recursion, clojure, lisp, tail-recursion

I'm trying to understand how Clojure's protection for `recur` in non-tail position works.

Clojure throws an exception if one writes code like that:

```clj
(def some_var (recur))
```

But what if I evaluate dynamically created code?

```clj
(def code '(recur))
(def some_var (eval code))
```

If you try to run this code in the REPL it seems to loop indefinitely. I expected it to throw an exception.

**My questions:**

When exactly does Clojure check if a recur was in tail position?

What are the exact semantics of my second code example (a recur in non-tail position executed dynamically)?

Comment: In your code using `eval` none of the lexical variables would be present, `recur` included. The error you get otherwise clearly shows it happens when compiling.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Am I understanding this correctly: If I `eval` code it gets it's own scope where recur is not defined?

Comment: Not exactly.. `eval` never uses the lexical scope of the code. Thus `(let [x 19] (eval 'x))` will either evaluate to the global variable `x` or throw an error that `x` is not bound. Thus you cannot even call a local function from within `eval` since the binding doesn't exist in the environment where it gets evaluated. This is true for the other lexically scoped lisp languages as well.

Comment: ah I see, thanks! So what my eval does is evaluating recur in the global environment? Do you know if the semantics of doing so are defined somewhere?

Comment: Also: Do you know of any other way I could evaluate recur in a non-tail position?

Comment: @Sylwester, `recur` is a special form, so I don't think this has anything to do with lexical bindings.

Comment: The whole point of `recur` is to provide tail calls. If you want to recurse in other places you use the name of the function instead. @NathanDavis How I read the spec it seems that macros that support calling it self in tail position perhaps handles `recur` specially and using `recur` for anything else would often not do what you want.

Comment: @Sylwester Macros have two implicit arguments: `(defmacro thingy [] (if false (recur 1 3) "Yabadabadoo!"))` compiles, and `(thingy)` evaluates to `"Yabadabadoo!"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Explanation of the observed behaviour (infinite loop)

Your `eval` call actually results in the compilation of code in which `recur` **does** occur in tail position.

This is because of how `eval` is implemented – if you pass a form to `eval` which is a Clojure persistent collection, but which doesn't look like a `def` form, it gets wrapped in an `fn` form, that `fn` form is what is actually compiled, and then the resulting function is called.

Here's how this applies to your example:

```
(eval '(recur))

;; does '(recur) look like a def form?
;; → no, so transform the above, in effect, to
((eval '(fn [] (recur)))

;; more precisely, before handing off `'(recur)` to lower-level
;; compilation methods, wrap it in `(fn [] …)`:
(fn [] (recur))

;; then immediately call the resulting function with no arguments

;; ultimate result: loop endlessly
```

If you want to see where this happens, have a look at the `public static Object eval(Object form, boolean freshLoader)` method of `clojure.lang.Compiler` – [link to the code as of Clojure 1.8](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L6893).

Note that for the same reason typing `(recur)` into the built-in REPL currently (as of 1.9.0-alpha14) also loops endlessly. Different REPL implementations may or may not preprocess input forms in ways that prevent this before handing them off to `eval`.

#### Semantics of `recur`

These are exactly as explained in the official docs that Alex Miller linked to, in his answer and in comments thereon. To summarize, `recur` must be used inside a form that establishes a `recur` target; `loop`, `fn` and `reify` (inside method implementations) are all examples of such forms.

#### How the semantics are enforced

The above semantics are enforced at compilation time through the use of a handful of dynamic Vars that the compiler binds appropriately as it descends into various subforms of the top-level form passed for compilation. If you want to follow the control flow in detail, search for usages of `NO_RECUR`, `LOOP_LABEL` and `LOOP_LOCALS` in Compiler.java. The gist of it is that if a form is not in tail position, these Vars will be bound to values that indicate that this is the case while it is compiled.

ClojureScript uses a setup that's probably a little easier to follow, although it's based on the same basic idea. See [analyzer.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/v1.9/src/main/clojure/cljs/analyzer.cljc) (stable link using the v1.9 tag); specifically `*recur-frames*` and `disallowing-recur`.

Comment: @le_me Cheers, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

> CompilerException java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can only recur from tail position

`CompilerException` would indicate the exception is thrown (and thus the check is performed) when the form is compiled.  In the case of `eval`, the form is compiled immediately prior to evaluating it.

Also, from the doc for [`recur`](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#recur) (emphasis added):

> recur is functional and its use in tail-position is **verified by the *compiler***.

Note that (technically), `(recur)` is a form in which `recur` occurs in tail position, although I think it would be difficult to argue it is correct to use `recur` outside of a form that establishes a recursion point (e.g., `fn` or `loop`).

Comment: Re: "although I think it would be difficult to argue it is correct to use recur outside of a fn or loop form" – `recur` must be used inside a form that establishes a `recur` target, however `fn` and `loop` and not the only such forms; for example you can `recur` to the head of a `reify`-implemented method (and this is documented in the docstring of `reify`).

Comment: thank you for your answer! I didn't accept yours, because Michal's answer is more detailed.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk, I was trying to keep things simple by singling out `fn` and `loop`.  But yes, there are other forms that establish a recursion point.  However, the documentation doesn't explicitly forbid the use of `recur` outside of any form that establishes a recursion point.  So although it's reasonable to infer that `(recur)` at the top-level should be rejected (at *least* at run-time, if not at compile-time), the behavior is technically unspecified.  That's the point I was trying to make with that statement.

Comment: @NathanDavis Sure, that's fair enough. I only commented in the interests of completeness; had your edit introducing the "e.g." happened earlier, I wouldn't have commented. As for the docs, I agree that one can reasonably argue that `recur` with no recursion point has undefined behaviour, although the phrasing that presupposes the presence of a recursion point ("the bindings of the recursion point", "Execution then jumps back to the recursion point" etc.) suggests this may be unintended. NB. here this is actually a better justification for the observed behaviour than the alternative.

Comment: I tend to take the unqualified use of the definite article as a fairly strong indication that `recur` with no recursion point is to be considered an error, and more importantly at a higher level that section's phrasing seems odd unless one makes this assumption (given no explicit disavowal). Certainly removing any remaining ambiguity by adding an explicit statement to this effect wouldn't hurt, though, and it'd be nice to throw on `(eval '(recur))` (and `(recur)` at a `clojure.main` REPL). (It might actually be less of a hassle to make it so than touching the `recur` mechanism usually is…)

Answer (score -1):

`recur` is a special form understood by the compiler. recur in any position other than the tail position is an error (and that is the semantics).

More detail is documented here: https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#recur

Comment: The question isn't about the semantics of `recur`.  It is about when the tail-position check occurs.

Comment: The compiler checks that the recur is in tail position when it encounters it. Depending on the context, that usage is either in tail position, or an error. There are some tricky cases related to try/finally (as the finally block is invoked after the try body).

Your last question was "What are the semantics of ... recur in ..." ?

Comment: Well, the way I read the question, it's asking specifically about the semantics of `recur` as used in the example given in the question, namely `(eval '(recur))`.  In other words, what are the semantics of `recur` when used outside of a `fn` / `loop` form?  I don't see that addressed anywhere in the docs.

Comment: `recur` is not allowed outside a `fn` / `loop` form, so the semantics are that it is an error.

Comment: Yet the observed behavior is an infinite loop, rather than an error.  So that's a bug?

Comment: Sure. It might not be a bug worth fixing though.

Comment: I'm looking for official documentation that describes the expected outcome of using recur outside of fn/loop

Comment: @le_me And Alex has given you a link to the two paragraphs in the official documentation that contain answers to your two questions. Question 1: "When exactly does Clojure check if a recur was in tail position?"; answer 1 (and I quote from the linked-to page): "recur is functional and its use in tail-position is verified by the compiler". Question 2: "What are the exact semantics of my second code example (a recur in non-tail position executed dynamically)?"; answer 2 (and again I quote from the same page): "recur in other than a tail position is an error".

Comment: Now, the linked-to page doesn't actually state that `recur` must occur inside a `fn` or a `loop` form, but that's because that isn't the case – for example protocol/interface method implementations in `reify` forms also constitute `recur` targets (this is documented in the docstring of `reify`). Not sure if there's an exhaustive list of all possible built-in `recur` targets anywhere.